# Something causing a huge slowdown in the execution of the DriveApp.getFileById + Utilities.parseCsv

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The `CSV` file usually has about 10 lines with values, it is small, light but even so all executions take 200 seconds to be able to import the values from the `CSV` file into a spreadsheet.

What might be causing this and what should I change in the code to make it work quickly?

[image]

```
function ImportWebData() {
  const cleansheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ImportWebData');
  cleansheet.getRange('A1:Z' + cleansheet.getMaxRows()).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ImportWebData');
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1aYQLX-67EFJKbGy9TFnis1vjtxiro3r8");
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Note: `Drive API` is active in `Google Advanced Services`

Comment: How big is your CSV? How many rows and columns?

Comment: @lambichus 10 lines and 6 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I avoided the unnecessary step of clearing data that may not be there by not using getMaxRows() I just used sh.getLastRow();  I probably could have used getLastColumn() for the data but I don't know what's inside the file.**

```
function ImportWebData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('ImportWebData');
  sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),26).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1aYQLX-67EFJKbGy9TFnis1vjtxiro3r8")
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  sh1.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

#### I guess you made it public and it ran in just few seconds

Comment: Hello mate, unfortunately the runtime with your indication was 148 seconds and another 208 seconds and with a failure alert. Is this the time to be able to import so little data from a CSV file? Or could there be a problem with the GAS system itself?

Comment: Not for me.  It only took a couple of seconds.

Comment: If I were you I'd shut down that spreadsheet and start it again. Maybe even the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately even the automated trigger is taking the same time as I mentioned, there must be some problem that there is no way I can solve it. Thanks for support mate!

Comment: I think I'd shut down the computer reboot and try it again and if that does not work I'd try  copying the container and move to another.  Sometimes files get corrupted and they just will not work.